# Uikit Icons with React and Next.js

Tags: reactjs, uikit, next.js

Having trouble getting uikit icons to appear in my next.js react app.

I've added the links to the Head in the _app.js. I have tried both linking to the node_modules (which is what i have left the css and js files as) as well as linking directly to the CDN. Everything is currently working except the icons.

```
<Head>
    {/**  UIkit */}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
    <script src="/uikit/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.4.6/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</Head>
```

When linking directly it made no difference either.

```
import '../node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.js';
```

I have also tried the Webpack method which some have said solved the issue. However it made no changes for me.

```
import UIkit from 'uikit';
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons';

// loads the Icon plugin
UIkit.use(Icons);
```

I feel like it may be Next.js which is causing the problem. Is there anyone that has had any experience with making this work? Would really appreciate any tips.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve the issue? I'm facing the same problem. Personally I get icons at certain times, while at other these don't show up.

Answer (score 5):

I had the a similar problem, but I have managed to integrate UIKit into NextJs. First I created a UIKit component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class UIKit extends Component {
  state = { ready: false };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const uikit = require("uikit");
      const icons = require("uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min");
      uikit.use(icons);
      this.setState({ ready: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}

export default UIKit;
```

Then I defined my custom `_app.tsx`:

```js
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";

import Navbar from "../components/navbar/navbar";
import UIKit from "../components/uikit";

// Global scss
import "../styles/uikit.scss";
import "../styles/global.scss";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Strapi bloggg</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches"
        />
      </Head>
      <UIKit>
        <Navbar />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </UIKit>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see the `UIKit` component will wrap everything around, on every page.

Finally I have made a `uikit.scss` in which I'm overriding some of the variables of the default theme. This is imported as `import "../styles/uikit.scss";`

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to integrate UiKit with NextJs "manually" by including the Scripts tags in a custom app. By default the `next/script` Script loads the UiKit packages after the Framework itself has been loaded.

With this UiKit checks the `data-uk-**` attrs to initialize itself without affecting React.

I don't know if this is the best way to integrate UiKit, but thanks to this I haven't had any problems with any UiKit component

`src/pages/_app.js`

```
import React from 'react';

// import App from 'next/app'
import Head from "next/head";
import Script from 'next/script'

import 'assets/styles.css'
import 'assets/uikit.theme.css'

import Layout from 'components/layout';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Head>
                <title>title</title>
                <meta name="description" content="description" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
                <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bundles/uikit/uikit.min.css"/>
            </Head>
            <Layout>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
            <Script src="/bundles/uikit/uikit.min.js"/>
            <Script src="/bundles/uikit/uikit-icons.min.js"/>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
    
}
  
  // Only uncomment this method if you have blocking data requirements for
  // every single page in your application. This disables the ability to
  // perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to
  // be server-side rendered.
  //
  // MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  //   // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  //   const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  //
  //   return { ...appProps }
  // }
  
export default MyApp
```