# UI Kit Icon Not Rendering on Load

Tags: reactjs, next.js, uikit

I have a nextjs blog that I'm working on and one of the components I'm using is this card component:

```
function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-width-1-2@m">
      <div className="uk-card-header">
        <div
          className="uk-grid-small uk-flex-middle"
          uk-grid
          uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-left; repeat: true"
        >
          <div className="uk-width-auto">
            <Image
              alt="Profile Picture"
              className="uk-border-circle"
              src={props.pic}
              height={200}
              width={200}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="uk-width-expand">
            <h3 className="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom">
              {props.name}
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="uk-card-body">
        <p>{props.description}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="uk-card-footer">
      <a href={props.linkedin} uk-icon="linkedin" className="footerbutton"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I take that component and use it in the page like so:

```
export default Main =()=> {
return(
            <Card
              pic={placeholderpic}
              linkedin='https://www.linkedin.com/'
              name="Harry Truman"
              description="Lorem ipsum"
            />
    )
}
```

The icon in the footer does not render until the page is refreshed 3-4 times. All the rest of the card renders properly on first load. Ideally I'd like to know 3 things:

A. Why this is occurring?
B. How to troubleshoot this in the future?
C. What the most appropriate fix is for this.

Edit:
This question is essentially the same as mine:

[Uikit Icons with React and Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764860/uikit-icons-with-react-and-next-js)

The solution for me is less than ideal, I don't want to wrap everything in a custom "UIKit" component.

Comment: In general, react should not be used with libraries that directly manipulate the DOM. It can and will overwrite any modifications to the DOM that uikit makes through their convenience HTML attributes. The result is a race condition. It could possibly work if you use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) but its a problem best avoided by using better engineered UI kits.

Comment: @AndrewGillis yeah ideally that would be the case. I'm using a starter template from Strapi to cut down on development time and in this case they elected to use UIKit. I suppose I could switch to another ui provider but in the interest of time I'd rather not.

Comment: Using the CSS features of UI kit is perfectly fine, but you should not use any of the JS powered features (interactions, modals, etc.). Maybe just find an alternative for your icons ([react-icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/) is popular as it wraps many of the free icon packs)

Comment: Understood. With the starter I used they did use JS stuff unfortunately.